# C# How to update xml file using XDocument class when xml file generated by dataset WriteXml() function

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am looking for some guide line how to update my complicated XML with `XDocument`. XML looks complicated because it is generated from `DataSet.WriteXml()`

Here is my XML first which was generated by `QCSavedData.WriteXml(@strQCViewAllPath);` QCSavedData is dataset:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<HNNMY_ViewAll>
    <dgvViewAll_Vertical>
        <Section_x0020_>MS</Section_x0020_>
        <LineItem>Morgan Stanley</LineItem>
        <Revise_x0020_Date>10-09-2020</Revise_x0020_Date>
        <_x0032_010_x0020_FYA>126,966.0000</_x0032_010_x0020_FYA>
        <_x0032_011_x0020_FYA>128,810.0000</_x0032_011_x0020_FYA>
        <_x0032_012_x0020_FYA>140,948.0000</_x0032_012_x0020_FYA>
        <_x0032_013_x0020_FYA>150,090.0000</_x0032_013_x0020_FYA>
        <_x0031_Q_x0020_2014A>37,524.0000</_x0031_Q_x0020_2014A>
        <_x0032_Q_x0020_2014A>44,181.0000</_x0032_Q_x0020_2014A>
        <_x0033_Q_x0020_2014A>45,259.0000</_x0033_Q_x0020_2014A>
        <_x0034_Q_x0020_2014A>49,656.0000</_x0034_Q_x0020_2014A>
        <_x0032_014_x0020_FYA>176,620.0000</_x0032_014_x0020_FYA>
        <_x0031_Q_x0020_2015A>46,791.0000</_x0031_Q_x0020_2015A>
        <_x0032_Q_x0020_2015A>53,233.0000</_x0032_Q_x0020_2015A>
        <_x0033_Q_x0020_2015A>53,420.0000</_x0033_Q_x0020_2015A>
        <_x0034_Q_x0020_2015A>56,477.0000</_x0034_Q_x0020_2015A>
        <_x0032_015_x0020_FYA>209,921.0000</_x0032_015_x0020_FYA>
        <_x0031_Q_x0020_2016A>50,624.0000</_x0031_Q_x0020_2016A>
        <_x0032_Q_x0020_2016A>54,341.0000</_x0032_Q_x0020_2016A>
        <_x0033_Q_x0020_2016A>56,802.0000</_x0033_Q_x0020_2016A>
        <GroupKey>Consensus Model~Total Revenue Including VAT~RD_001~NBM~~1~MS</GroupKey>
    </dgvViewAll_Vertical>
</HNNMY_ViewAll>
```

1. see this is **`<Section_x0020_>MS</Section_x0020_>`** how to query when section is MS because Section has ***x0020***?
2. see this one
   **`<_x0032_010_x0020_FYA>126,966.0000</_x0032_010_x0020_FYA>`**
   datatable has many columns like 2010 FYA, 2011 FYA .... 1Q 2014A but when datatable data saved in xml then it is showing like this way **`<_x0032_010_x0020_FYA>126,966.0000</_x0032_010_x0020_FYA>`** then how could I update value inside this tag ?
3. see this one **`<GroupKey>Consensus Model~Total Revenue Including VAT~RD_001~NBM~~1~MS</GroupKey>`**

I have to query like this way by

`XDocument` that when **Section == GroupKey.Split('~')[5]** AND **Column Name is 2010 FYA** then update the value inside of **column 2010 FYA** means this column's value **`<_x0032_010_x0020_FYA>126,966.0000</_x0032_010_x0020_FYA>`**

Please help me with sample code which guide me how to update my XML.

Comment: The only reason it is complicated is because you dataset column names have spaces and starts with a number.  Xml tags do not allow the first character to be a number nor does it allow for spaces in the tag names.

Comment: Sir can you please share some idea how to update my xml data using xdocument class.

Comment: You need to fix the column names or use "AS" to map names to something else.  What query are you using to get data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a `DataSet` is written to XML, the output is shown in the documentation for [`DataTable.WriteXml()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.writexml?view=net-5.0#examples).  It will look like:

```xml
<DataSetName>  
  <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <!--Schema information here, if you have requested it -->
  </xs:schema>  
  <!--The first table: -->
  <Table1Name>  <!--This repeats for every row in Table1 -->
    <!-- Column values -->
    <Column1Name>Value 1.1</Column1Name>  
    <Column2Name>Value 2.1</Column2Name>  
  </Table1Name>  
  <Table1Name> 
    <!-- Column values -->
    <Column1Name>Value 1.2</Column1Name>  
    <Column2Name>Value 2.2</Column2Name>  
  </Table1Name>  
  <!--The second table: -->
  <Table2Name>  <!--This repeats for every row in Table2 -->
    <!-- Column values -->
    <ColumnName>Value</ColumnName>  
  </Table2Name>  
  <!--And the remaining tables if any follow sequentially -->
</DataSetName>
```

Notice that the data set, table and column names become XML element names.  However, not every string can be used as a well-formed XML element name, which is defined by the [XML standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/#NT-Name).  Simplifying a little, a well-formed element name must:

- Start with a Unicode letter or `_`.
- Subsequently consist of Unicode alphanumeric characters, `_`, `-` or `.`.

Thus `2010 FYA` cannot be a well-formed XML element name, as it starts with a numeric character and contains spaces.  So, in situations like this, the framework uses [`XmlConvert.EncodeLocalName(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlconvert.encodelocalname?view=net-5.0) to encode arbitrary strings to well-formed XML names:

> This method is similar to the [`EncodeName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlconvert.encodename?view=net-5.0) method except that it encodes the colon character, which guarantees that the name can be used as the local name part of a namespace qualified name.

And the related [`XmlConvert.EncodeName(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlconvert.encodename?view=net-5.0):

> This method translates invalid characters, such as spaces or half-width Katakana, that need to be mapped to XML names without the support or presence of schemas. The invalid characters are translated into escaped numeric entity encodings.
>
> The escape character is "_". Any XML name character that does not conform to the [XML 1.0 spec (fourth edition)](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/) recommendation is escaped as *xHHHH*. The HHHH string stands for the four-digit hexadecimal UCS-2 code for the character in most significant bit first order. For example, the name Order Details is encoded as Order_x0020_Details.
>
> The underscore character does not need to be escaped unless it is followed by a character sequence that together with the underscore can be misinterpreted as an escape sequence when decoding the name. For example, Order_Details is not encoded, but Order_x0020_ is encoded as Order_x005f_x0020_. No shortforms are allowed. For example, the forms *x20* and __ are not generated.

If you want to query the XML with a data set, table or column name, you must call `XmlConvert.EncodeLocalName(name)` to determine the name used in the XML.  Conversely, if you want to query the data set with some element name read from the XML, you must call [`XmlConvert.DecodeName(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlconvert.decodename?view=net-5.0) to regenerate the original name.

E.g. to update the `2010 FYA` column(s) in some `XDocument xdocument`, you could do:

```
var tableName = XmlConvert.EncodeLocalName("dgvViewAll_Vertical"); // EncodeLocalName is not strictly needed here since dgvViewAll_Vertical happens to be a well-formed XML name
var sectionName = XmlConvert.EncodeLocalName("Section ");
var groupKeyName = XmlConvert.EncodeLocalName("GroupKey"); // EncodeLocalName is not strictly needed here since GroupKey happens to be a well-formed XML name
var columnName = XmlConvert.EncodeLocalName("2010 FYA");

var columnValue = "New Value";

var ns = xdocument.Root.Name.Namespace;
var columns = xdocument.Root
    .Elements(ns + tableName)
    // Add error handling here when groupKeyName is not found or not in the expected syntax
    .Where(e => e.Element(ns + sectionName)?.Value == e.Element(ns + groupKeyName).Value.Split('~').Last()) 
    .Select(e => e.Element(ns + columnName));

foreach (var column in columns)
{
    column.Value = columnValue;
}
```

Note this code assumes that your [data set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.namespace?view=net-5.0), [data tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.namespace?view=net-5.0) and [data columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.namespace?view=net-5.0) all use the same XML namespace (`ns` in the code above).  This is true for the XML shown in your question.  When this is not true, the appropriate namespace will need to be used when querying table and column names.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3uA2nX).